# Line break error in enumerate's item (code compile as i want but i get an error report)

Tags: lists

Error is : `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at line 22-31`(lines of the second item)`

The code is :

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}



\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate} 
\item On lance un dé à 6 faces, alors $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.\\
Les évenements : A = ""le résultat est 1 ou 2 "", B = ""le résultat est un nombre impair""
\item On lance deux dés équilibrés à 6 faces\\
modèle 1\\
On suppose que l'on peut identifier les deux dés.\\
On observe un couple (i,j)\\
$\Omega_1 = \{(i,j), i \in \{1,...,6\} et j \in \{1,...,6\}$\\~\\
modèle 2\\
On suppose que l'on ne peut pas identifier les deux dés.\\
On observe un la réalisation d'une paire (i,j) qui correspond aux numéros ordonnés. Alors :\\
$\Omega_2 = \{(i,j), 1 \leq i \leq j \leq 6\}$

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I use this template : https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/course-notes-template/cshpnhwffshq

I'd like to know why i have an error even if my code compile.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `Underfull \hbox` is not an error, it is a warning.  That's why your code compiles despite that message. LaTeX uses this message to inform you that a box is too empty, e.g. a line contains very little text, leading to too much white space. Badness 10000 is the worst possible value, that means LaTeX does not find a satisfying result for your box.

Comment: that warning is almost always from misusing `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph but I don't see that here although `\\~\\ ` is fairly horrible markup and is what generates the warning nere as it is equivalent to `\\ \\ ` with an empty (underful) line) Do you really have `\ ` after the `\begin{enumerate}` or is that an error while pasting in to this site?

Comment: With this template, all my list did not break line when i used theorems environments. So i read that a way to make it was to put "\" right after beginning the list.

Answer (score 2):

```
\\~\\
```

is equivalent to

```
\\\\
```

and produces a spurious line of the paragraph that has no content so is necessarily under full and generates that warning.  It looks a bit like white space but it is actually a line of a paragraph and for example is not dropped if a page break happens at that point.

Most documents should have no instances of `\\` outside tables, but here you want some extra space so leave a blank line to start a new paragraph, then if necessary add a space such as `\bigskip`

```
$\Omega_1 = \{(i,j), i \in \{1,...,6\}$ et $j \in \{1,...,6\}$

\bigskip
\noindent modèle 2
```

Comment: I thought the bigskip was supposed to come before the paragraph break?

Comment: @Teepeemm no, vertical spaces are always best entered in vertical mode. `\bigskip` `\vspace` etc work somewhat strangely if used in horizontal mode.

Comment: If a blank line is left, the next non-blank line will usually be indented, so `\noindent` would also be wanted in that situation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thought about that better would be a nested list so the model 1 and model2 were proper item headings, but was trying to keep it simple. I'll add the noindent

Comment: Thanks, why is blank space a bad thing in latex ? Also, I though latex did not take (in code) blank line as a thing that interact with code.

Comment: @Eps I am not sure I understand your comment. a blank line is the same as `\par` and ends the current paragraph. It is not a bad thing